# Not able to load a file from flutter

Tags: flutter

I write this code to save an list as csv file

```
  generatecsv() async {
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      String dir = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path;
      String filep = "$dir/csvdatasave.csv";
      File f = new File(filep);
      String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(_logdata);
      f.writeAsString(csv);
      print("gen complete");
    } else {
      Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
        Permission.storage,
      ].request();
    }
  }
```

It worked...and it generated the file...
But i can't load the file to app again...
This is my code...

```
 _loadedCSV() async {
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      String dir = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path;
      String filep = "$dir/csvdatasave.csv";
      print(filep);
      final _rawData = await rootBundle.loadString(filep);
      _loadlistData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(_rawData);
      print("from csv");
      print(_loadlistData);
      print("loaded from csv file ");
    } else {
      Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
        Permission.storage,
      ].request();
    }
  }
```

It shows this error...
`Exception has occurred. FlutterError (Unable to load asset: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.dpark/files/csvdatasave.csv)`
but the file exists

Can anyone help to load the generated csv file from the saved location...

Answer (score 0):

`rootBundle` is a Helper instance of a class by type `AssetBundle` that provide to load app resources.
(something like `ResourceManager` in Net framework) and allows you to load resources only by a **specific position** (before compiling are all inside `/assets` folder).

To load file by everywhere you must use `File` class of `dart:io` by using import 'dart:io'
then:

Sync

```
final Uint8List readAsBytesSync = new File(pathHere).readAsBytesSync();
final String readAsStringSync = new File(pathHere).readAsStringSync();
```

Or Async

```
final Future<Uint8List> readAsBytes = new File(pathHere).readAsBytes();
final Future<String> readAsString = new File(pathHere).readAsString();
```